# Creating public key certificates with a pre-existing public key value

Tags: php, openssl, pki

I was just wondering how it would be possible to create a public key certificate using php with only a pre-computed public key value.  I will just sign this certificate using my own ca cert once I have the public key and remaining values entered.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it can be done by the nature of certificates. You can't use a pre-existing public key, or people could spoof your identity...

Comment: it almost seems like a one-two step process, so at the moment, i haven't found anything adequate to try.  all of the openssl certs require private key creation as well.  However this is being done in a public key infrastructure and I'm keeping the public keys separate from the private keys which are held on the server and client respectively.

Comment: IIRC this is what Certificate Signing Requests [CSRs] are for.

Comment: right, that's what's being made with openssl, however how can I make a CSR using just a public key and openssl(or any other library for that matter)?

Comment: You need private key to make CSR. Otherwise, you have to do an attack on your public key to derive its private key.

Answer (score 2):

An X.509 cert has a subject and an issuer. If all you have is the subject's public key you can still create a CA signed cert with the CA's private key. Using [phpseclib, a pure PHP X.509 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)...

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

// load private key for issuer / CA
$CAPrivKey = new Crypt_RSA();
$CAPrivKey->loadKey('...');

// load public key for subject
$pubKey = new Crypt_RSA();
$pubKey->loadKey('...');
$pubKey->setPublicKey();

// create the DN for the subject
$subject = new File_X509();
$subject->setDN('...');
$subject->setPublicKey($pubKey);

// create the DN for the issuer
// (the DN can be loaded from another X.509 cert too)
$issuer = new File_X509();
$issuer->setPrivateKey($CAPrivKey);
$issuer->setDN('...');

$x509 = new File_X509();
$x509->setStartDate('-1 month');
$x509->setEndDate('+1 year');

$result = $x509->sign($issuer, $subject);
echo $x509->saveX509($result);
?>
```